# How not to run the onclick on an anchor link if it has been clicked as open in new tab (ctrl and click on windows)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link.

If I click it the javascript for the onclick runs and we do not go to the href address.  This is good.

If I right click it and choose open in new tab then we only go to the href address in a new tab and the onclick does not run.  This is also good.

If I cntl and click (on windows - command and click on ios) then the onclick runs (presumably because a click has happened) and I go to the href address in a new tab.  I don't want this.  I just want the new tab to open.

```html
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" onclick="arguments[0].stopPropagation(); alert('Clicked')">Do some stuff</a>
```

Either - can I detect that my onclick also caused a new tab to open so I can choose not to run my code.

Or, is there another event I should be listening for.

What I want to happen on a ctrl and click is - new tab opens, my javascript code does not run (or I can choose what to do).

I need something that works across all (latest) browsers and operating systems if possible.  I.e. I'd prefer not to have to check if cntr(17) was pressed.  I would prefer to know the intent of the click was to open a new tab - I was hoping to see a dynamic target attribute on the event but I couldn't find it.

(PS - ignore the fact that arguments[0] might not exist in all browsers - this is just an example of my problem)

I don't think this is a duplicate of knowing if the control key was pressed (although it may well turn out to be the only way of checking).  I am asking if there is a way of differentiating between targeting a link in a new window/tab and targeting a link in the same tab.

Comment: Throwing ideas out there, but perhaps: `preventDefault()` > Your action of choice > Use JS to open the requested page (If you want to)

Comment: Hi pherris - the only answer may well be to check the ctrl key - I was hoping there was a better cross platform / browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding 'return false;' to the end of onclick=".." - that way the href=... bit only fires if javascript is disabled or is by-passed.